# get text inside a html element

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using HTMLAgilityPack to get text inside a list of certain nodes.
Basically I'm reading out a HTML page with the following HTML:

```
<div class="video-overview yt-grid-fluid">
   <h3 class="video-title-container">
       <span class="yt-badge-std">
            WATCHED
        </span>
      <a href="/watch?v=S5FCdx7Dn0o&amp;list=FLArRQZAMoAgECBIOn08gNeA&amp;index=1" title="Bob Marley - Buffalo soldier" class="yt-uix-tile-link yt-uix-sessionlink" data-sessionlink="ei=c9tWUb3eJaOzhgG6kYHYAg&amp;feature=plpp_video">
        <span class="title video-title" dir="ltr">Bob Marley - Buffalo soldier</span>
      </a>
   </h3>

      <p class="video-details">
        <span class="video-owner">
             by <span class="yt-user-name " dir="ltr">Pgroenberg</span>
        </span>

          <span class="video-view-count">
            44,342,136 views
          </span>
      </p>
  </div>
```

I want to get the text "Bob Marley - Buffalo soldier", which is inside `<span class="title video-title" dir">`.

I cant seem to find the right pattern:

```
string expression = @"//span[@class='title video-title' and @dir='ltr']/text()";
HtmlNodeCollection hnc = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(expression);
```

hnc will be null because no nodes have matched with the expression. Why wont my expression work?

Comment: It can be that HAP sometimes changes the order of values inside attributes (this is at least my understanding). Does this work? `//span[contains(@class,'video-title')]`.

Comment: @alexn nope, hnc is still null.

Comment: And you did call LoadHtml?

Comment: Yes, the HTML page is loaded inside a string and loaded into the HAP.HtmlDocument object

Comment: Just tried it over here and it definitely works. Check this gist out https://gist.github.com/alexandernyquist/5276927. `html` is the exact html from your question.

Comment: @alexn I'm reading out a playlist on youtube. I think its reading out the wrong page because youtube is redirecting me to some other page. Thanks for your time dude, I'm a big step further now.

Comment: @alexn lol it turned out I entered the wrong GET parameter, inside the youtube url. Very stupid mistake =\ Open up a answer if you want, your answer helped me find the problem.